# Visual Studio 2015 C# Automatic BUILD before RUN doesn't work since yesterday

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, build

I have a small trouble with my C# **BUILD & RUN** 
Since yesterday , my BUILD is not automatically lauched before RUN 
Now , I have to do SHIFT+F6 and F5 after 
I have cheked the only one parameter I know but all seems to be OK 
[Options screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4OVg.png) 
Could you help me to recover my old automatic process **BUILD & RUN** please ? 
Thank you 
Chris

Comment: Try going in to the bin folder and delete all vhost files.  If you are on a network the vhost are lock files do prevent multiple users from compiling in same folder.

Comment: I have tried but no changes , I have found several *.vshost.* files , after DELETE them , the BUILD & RUN is always OFF , it runs without build/compile the project ( with old version , last build )

Comment: You must have a compile error.  Did you try a clean build?

Comment: Sorry but I have no compile error , I've already done a clean without changes , restart Visual Studio of course , and restart my computer too

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved
I have checked the build parameter in configuration manager

[image]